# boost::copy_file copy_option to skip over existing destination file?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I would like to copy a file to an other, and I would like to use Boost::copy_file. It has a paramether called copy_option which can be:

```
  BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START(copy_option)
    {none, fail_if_exists = none, overwrite_if_exists};
  BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END
```

I have found another question regarding the `overwrite_if_exists` behaviour here: [how to perform boost::filesystem copy_file with overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829468/how-to-perform-boostfilesystem-copy-file-with-overwrite)

My problem however is that I don't know how to use the `fail_if_exists = none` option. I would like to **skip** the copy operation, if the target file already exists.

I know its possible with `if ( !exists(path) )` but I want to understand how does `copy_option` work.

How can I use `fail_if_exists = none` inside Boost::copy_file function?

**Update**: corrected the code, [the one on boost doc website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_option) is kind of broken.

Comment: My version of Boost doesn't have `none` there. Which version are you using? And there should be a comma after `none` in the code you posted.

Comment: You are rigth, the one in documentation is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `copy_option` to just skip the copy if the destination already exists.

But `if (!exists(path)) copy_file(...)` is not the right answer, either, because of the race condition:  The file might be created between the time you perform the existence check and the time you attempt the copy.  So even when you check for the file's existence, `copy_file` might fail.

The way to synthesize what you want is to catch the error and ignore it yourself.  Something like this:

```
try {
    copy_file(...);
}
catch (const boost::system::system_error &err) {
    if (!err.code().equivalent(boost::system::errc::file_exists))
        throw;
}
```

Comment: seems pretty inefficient to promote exceptions to normal workflow.. using variant returning error_code would be probably better

Answer (score 0):

This goes back to [this proposal](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/03/149371.php) in order to allow for smoother transition of an old scoped-enum-hack to clean-c++0x-enum-classes:

```
 namespace FooEnum {
     enum type {
         SomeValue
     }
 }
```

Users could then write `FooEnum::SomeValue` and value-name collisions were avoided. C++0x will have native support for this.

So, you would just use `<enum-name>::<enum-value>`, i.e. `copy_option::none` etc.